# Adding list of options to HTML5 select tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I've the below HTML code, and need to update the "option" element dynamically, by a big list of elements coming back from the server

```
<select id='select'>
     <option value = '0' selected></option>
</select>
```

So, I wrote the below JS code:

```
var select = e.querySelector('#select');

for(var k=0; k<5;k++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value=data[k].value;
    opt.text=data[k].text;
    select.add(opt);
}
```

I do not need to use JQuery or any other plugin.

Is there a more neat and/or simpler way to do the same?

Comment: I think thats the least you have to do without using any plugin. I would suggest you use `for(var k in data)`.

Comment: @HarryBomrah: 1. No, it isn't. 2. `for-in` isn't for iterating arrays, [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Option` constructor:

```
var select = e.querySelector('#select');
for(var k=0; k<5;k++){
    select.options.add(new Option(data[k].text, data[k].value));
}
```

Live example:

```js
var data = [
  {text: "Option 1", value: "1"},
  {text: "Option 2", value: "2"},
  {text: "Option 3", value: "3"},
  {text: "Option 4", value: "4"},
  {text: "Option 5", value: "5"}
];
var select = document.querySelector('#select');
for(var k=0; k<5;k++){
    select.options.add(new Option(data[k].text, data[k].value));
}
```

```html
<select id="select" size="10"></select>
```

Assuming `data` is an array, you can also use `Array#forEach`:

```
var select = e.querySelector('#select');
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    select.options.add(new Option(entry.text, entry.value));
});
```

Live example:

```js
var data = [
  {text: "Option 1", value: "1"},
  {text: "Option 2", value: "2"},
  {text: "Option 3", value: "3"},
  {text: "Option 4", value: "4"},
  {text: "Option 5", value: "5"}
];
var select = document.querySelector('#select');
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    select.options.add(new Option(entry.text, entry.value));
});
```

```html
<select id="select" size="10"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect, I tried "new document.createElement('option');" but did not work, and thought it is silly to mention it :), thanks again.

Comment: It worked with both select.options.add, and select.add

Comment: @HasanAYousef: Huh, well [look at that](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-add), `HTMLSelectElement` has an `add`. Interesting!